# Questions about Divs; hover, active, content

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover

So I've run into a wall...and it's possible it's because I'm tired. Here is my current fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Sketchs/vAx84/

How do I make the divs highlight when I hover over them, and more specifically stay a certain color, red for example, when they are the active tab.  Then, how do I push information into the "content" div?  Should I use jQuery to appendTo?

Thanks

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="details">details:</div>
<div id="description">description:</div>
```

Content Goes Here

Comment: what do you mean by active tab

Comment: You tagged your question with jQuery but posted none.

Comment: you can use the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo class

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GC89f/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vAx84/2/

I added class **btn** so when you write css, you append rules for all buttons:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="details" class="btn">details:</div>
    <div id="description" class="btn">description:</div>
</div>
<div id="content">Content Goes Here</div>
```

CSS to highlight when you are hovering:

```
.btn:hover{
 background: #000 !important;   
}
```

To make your div active you could create active css class in your css file:

```
.active{
background: red;
}
```

and then append that class on click like this with jQuery:

```
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        $(".btn").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

This will color your current clicked button to red(active button).

To put information to content div you can use jQuery like this:

```
$("#details").text("some text");
```

or on click on details button for example:

```
    $("#details").on("click", function(){
   $("#content").text("some text");
});
```

Please check whole working example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vAx84/2/

Comment: Thanks! Adding the class didn't work, but I'll keep researching. You answered most of the questions.

Comment: added jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/vAx84/2/ . if it helped please upvote my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

to get the color on mouse over simply add `:hover` to a new class for the tabs:

CSS:

```
#details:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
   }

#description:hover {
    background-color:red;
   }
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vAx84/1/

Comment: That's helpful, but I'm looking for a way to keep it that color once it's the active, selected, tab.